# Как поднять кнопку, когда над ней курсор в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, hover

Делаю меню для игры, нужно сделать hover для кнопки, как это реализовать? Я пытался, но ничего не происходит. Sprite Renderer на кнопке есть.

Код:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Hover : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    public Renderer spriteRenderer;
    private void Start()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        spriteRenderer.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Коллайдер есть?

Comment: [IPointerEnterHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html), [IPointerExitHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerExitHandler.html) и иные `IPointer` интерфейсы для обработки `UI` эвентов.